# Opening a pdf with pdf.js with Xamarin on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, pdf.js

I'm trying to open a pdf file with pdf.js using Xamarin on a Windows Phone app but I can't get it to work.

It displays the pdf.js viewer.html correctly but I just can't get it to open the pdf file. I've tried the following:

```
PdfWebViewer.Source = "Assets/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?
file=ms-appx:///Assets/Temp/test.pdf";

PdfWebViewer.Source = "Assets/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?
file=Assets/Temp/test.pdf";

PdfWebViewer.Source = "Assets/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?
file=File:///Assets/Temp/test.pdf";

PdfWebViewer.Source = "Assets/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?
file=File://Assets/Temp/test.pdf";
```

For testing purposes, I have a test.pdf file in my Assets/Temp folder and its ContentType is set to Content.

But none of the combinations mentioned above work. Whenever I specify the file, I just get a 'page not found' displayed instead of the viewer.html

I need to display buttons at the bottom of the pdf, so I have to open the pdf **using my app**. To open the pdf using another app is not an option.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use pdf.js to open your PDFs? I'm not using pdf.js to open PDFs in my app, so I can't help you with that. But I'm opening PDFs from my app by launching the default PDF reader app installed by the user (such as Acrobat Reader or OneReader). If that's a viable option for you, let me know.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that we cannot leave the app as we need to display buttons at the bottom of the pdf, but Xamarin asked me to try to build a renderer with a webview and resize to fill the screen up to my toolbar. Maybe this will work. I'll give it a shot and will update this post if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Change the URI scheme as shown bellow:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

                MyView.Source = new Uri(String.Format("ms-appx-web:///Assets/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", "ms-appx-web:///Files/a1.pdf"));

// ms-appx-web:///thefolder in which file is available/filename.pdf
        }
```

Also note in windows you might not be able to access file system for PDF but only bundled pdf's